# Different download link to different country visitors

Tags: redirect, hyperlink

I am new to php and want to do the following:

If a user is from Germany he should see the link download.zip on my page.
If the user is from anywhere else he should see the link download2.zip on my page.

I am using WP and the current plugins allow only redirect for the whole page. I want only 1 link to be different from country to country.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The users location is based in the browser configuration (language), SO configuration or geolocation? If you are basing you decision in one of the first two, you can use javascript to get the country code and to decide what link you want to show. Take a look here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

Comment: I need geo location. I will take a look at that tutorial. THanks.